# Solr arabic exact search

Tags: solr, arabic

I am new to solr and I want to add a new field to schema to use it for Arabic exact search. I have searched a lot in Stackoverflow but could not find how to do it.

Here's my schema.xml :

*Field*

```
<field name="arsch" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"  required="true"/>
```

*Type*

```
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />
```

I'm always getting some other words with the search word.  For example, if I query for arsch: "امام" I get the following words:

```
"امام" 
"الامام"
"والامام" 
"الاماره"
```

I want this field to be exact, how to do it?